# How to declare type of "{ message }" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So, I was studying typescript and I've got a doubt about this: In a function like `player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message } ) => { console.error(message); });`, how do I declare the type of "`{message}`" ?

```typescript
var Spotify:any

    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
      
        script.src = "https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js";
        script.async = true;
      
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      
        return () => {
          document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
      }, []);

      (window as any).onSpotifyWebPlaybackSDKReady = () => {

        const token = '[My Spotify Web API access token]';
        const player = new Spotify.Player({
          name: 'Web Playback SDK Quick Start Player',
          getOAuthToken: (cb:any) => { cb(token); }
        });
      
        // Error handling
        player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message } ) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('authentication_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('account_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
        player.addListener('playback_error', ({ message }) => { console.error(message); });
      
        // Playback status updates
        player.addListener('player_state_changed', (state:any) => { console.log(state); });
      
        // Ready
        player.addListener('ready', ({ device_id }) => {
          console.log('Ready with Device ID', device_id);
        });
      
        // Not Ready
        player.addListener('not_ready', ({ device_id }) => {
          console.log('Device ID has gone offline', device_id);
        });
      
        // Connect to the player!
        player.connect();
      };
```

The whole code is that, I'm using TypeScript with React and the TypeScript is emitting a warning about the implicitly "any" type of message.

[image]

Comment: If `addListener` is being used, it should be typed already, so there shouldn't be a need to declare the type of `message`? Or is the problem that you need to declare the callback outside of `addListener`?

Comment: Look the edit pls

Comment: what is the full type signature of function `addListener` on `Player` class?

Answer (score 1):

[You can create an `interface` that provides the information of the parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgApynAWwGdkBvAKGSuSgjgBMB7EAGwE9kCIii4BzCAC5kRMFFB8A3OQC+5cgmajkkUcIAUABzyEiwjFjC58xAJTIAvAD5k6RsHqXk60p268ByGeetlKyRRAiRhYIADoWRj51Lh5+CFNpGWlyVTAXNziBYQAiAAkIFkjkAHdGKBZ6AEIcr0SgA):

```js
interface EventParams {
    readonly message: string;
}

const test: (params: EventParams) => void = ({ message }) => {
  console.log(message);
};

test({ message: "Hello world!" });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do:
`player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message:string } ) => { console.error(message); });`

Answer (score 1):

You can create interface:

```
interface ErrorInterface {
   message: string
}
```

And use it

```
player.addListener('initialization_error', ({ message }: ErrorInterface) => { console.error(message); });
```

You can read more about typescript and destructuring there:

https://flaviocopes.com/typescript-object-destructuring/

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning, then there are few things you should understand in this code:

- `addListener` is a function which already defined on `player`
- `addListener` function takes two arguments

  - 1st arg which is of type `string`
  - 2nd arg is a callback function which takes some type that has `message` field in it (you can check the exact type by navigating to `player`)
- `({message})` this is called object destructing, you are not defining type here but you are accessing concrete `message` field from object

Refer following example which depicts above things:

```js
type Person = { name: string; age: number }

// function definition and declaration where you provide explicit types
const printName = (cb: (p: Person) => void) => {
  cb({ name: 'primary', age: 30 })
}

// function call where you deal with values and types are already fixed in declaration
// printName gives you handle to person object but you are only interested in name,
// so you use destructuring here
printName(({ name }) => console.log(name))
```